# Render partial from jQuery ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I wanted to render a partial that contains a form inside of view from application js, I am reading the event of attached button without submitting because I need to process the headers of a file CSV before doing submit.

This is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#attached_attached_csv").change(function (e) {
    if (e.target.files != undefined) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
          // this line isn't working - I try of many ways, but none are working
          $("#text").html("<%= j render partial: 'layouts/form') %>".html_safe);
      };
      reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

I see also how any people using ajax, but I don't know how to use this for the trigger event of an attached button without submitting, I prob sending without html_safe but I obtain the string:

```
<%= j render partial: 'layouts/form') %>
```

My partial is  "layouts/form", which is a file with extension html.erb. here share where I found the code for handle the event http://jsfiddle.net/FSc8y/2/, but it's not important the most important for me its render the embedded ruby form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check you are not getting any errors in Javascript. e.g. `html_safe` is a method on Ruby string on not JS string and in the code above it is used on a JS string.

Comment: hi, yes when I quit html_safe this only renders the string "<%= j render partial: 'layouts/form') %>", with the html_safe don't render anything.

Comment: did you try `$("#text").html("<%= j render(partial: 'layouts/form'))%>".html_safe);`, that is, adding parentheses. Also, have you checked the rendered JS, what is this line showing?

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't render anything, the js file is rendering any other thing that I send, less the partials or embed ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails syntax in your javascript files by adding `.js.erb` extension to the file name like `my_file.js.erb`.

Comment: hi, how can I do that my view can read this file? it should de create inside the folder of my view o where, because I try to create this from my folder view, and this does not recognize the file.